# PowerCLI - find datastores in a available to a custer

Tags: powershell, powercli

I'm trying to find a way to get a list of datastores available in a cluster.
So far I got this far:

```
$1 = get-view -viewtype ClusterComputeResource
$1 | select name,datastore
```

that will list clasters and datastores but the names do not match those in vCenter server.
I can see both names but without the custer info when running this:

```
Get-Datastore | select id,name
```

How do I get those information together so I have ClusterName (Name - from the first command), DatastoreName (Name - from the second command).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right it took me a while but I found a way of doing it with the use of Join-Object fuction from here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2012/07/13/join-object/

```
$cluster = get-cluster | select name | % {$counter = -1} {$counter++; $_ | Add-Member -Name Cluster_ID -Value $counter -MemberType NoteProperty -PassThru}
$cluster | ft -auto
$clusterid = read-host "select cluster"
$VMCLUSTER = $cluster[$clusterid]

# Select Datastore
$1 = get-view -viewtype ClusterComputeResource | where name -like $vmcluster.name | select name,datastore
$table1 = @()
foreach ($datastore in $1.Datastore) {
$table = " " | select datastore_ID,Cluster_Name
$table.datastore_ID = $datastore
$table.Cluster_name =  $1.Name
$table1 += $table
}

$datastores = Join-Object -Left $table1 -Right (Get-datastore | select id,name,FreeSpaceGB,CapacityGB) -Where { $args[0].datastore_ID -eq $args[1].id} -LeftProperties 'Cluster_Name' -RightProperties * -Type AllInLeft
$datastores | % {$counter = -1} {$counter++; $_ | Add-Member -Name Datastore_ID -Value $counter -MemberType NoteProperty -PassThru} | select Datastore_ID,Cluster_Name,Name,FreeSpaceGB,CapacityGB | Sort-Object FreeSpaceGB -Descending | ft -AutoSize
$datastoreid = read-host "Select Datastore (enter Datastore_ID)"
$selected_datastore = $datastores[$datastoreid]
```

Answer (score 0):

this seems to do it

```
(get-cluster).extensiondata | fl name,datastore
```

edit to get name instead of id

```
$clusters = get-cluster
Foreach ($cluster in $clusters)
{
    $cluster | get-datastore | % {
    [pscustomobject] @{
    'cluster' = $cluster.name
    'datastore' = $_.name
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: nop, that's not it - it gives me the same output as the first two line I posted

Comment: added an edit with getting name instead of id...didn't see any cleaner way to do it than that. hopefully you're on powershell 3.0 or newer to use pscustomobject

Answer (score 0):

```
$datastore = Get-Datastore
$datastore.extensionData
```

This will give you a more detaile list of the stores. This one is hard. I think I may have to do it through the API.

Comment: nop, that's not it - it gives me the same output as the first two line I posted